# Google Chrome graphical glitches - AMD Radeon

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, 17.04, amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome

[image: Here Images in my problem]

How can I fix this? Sometime when scroll in some site the page is crashed or don't load on 100% I mean is blurry.

Comment: If you really want to fix it, grab the source code of the radeon driver, and start hacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all **Graphics Feature Status** option to  **Hardware accelerated** you need to enable the flag named as 
**Override software rendering list**.

In order to do this enter **chrome://flags** in address bar and then enable the flag.